# How to fix the position of the advanced panels in wordpress gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I noticed that in one of a client's sites the seo and content analysis tabs of the SeoPress plugin (which are normally under the main content) are now moved to the right sidebar (in the gutenberg editor). This happens only for articles, on the pages the tabs are positioned correctly (under the main content). Has it happened to anyone? How can I put the tabs back in their place?

To see the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/blwxocnvgn2dnn3/seopress-problem.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 4):

If it helps someone else who is facing the same problem, I solved it like this:

1 – install classic editor
2 – drag the panels where you want and save
3 – remove the classic editor

then open a post in gutenberg to see the panels finally in place.

Comment: Had the same problem now. Searched all over the internet for some options inside guthenburg, but doesn't seem to be anything. Installing classic editor does the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 arrows to the right of title of the panel which look like this: [image: move arrows for Gutenberg panel]

If you click the up arrow enough times the panel will move to the area under main content. Vise versa if you click the down arrow enough times the panel will move to the sidebar.

> Note: This move/sort ability is not available for WordPress core panels nor panels registered via Gutenberg's `PluginDocumentSettingPanel`
> panels and will only work for meta boxes added by plugins or themes.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm quite sure though that I've accidentally moved a panel to the bottom by this action. So it is a one way, only.